# SqLite Auto-increment for one its Composite Keys

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite, testing

[image: SqLite Composite Keys]

The following columns are set to auto-increment in SQL Server `IDENTITY(1,1)` and I wanted similar behavior on SqLite: Tenant.**TenantID**, Project.**ProjectID**, and Credits.**CreditsID**. Although there is `AUTOINCREMENT` in SqLite, and I have tried it, but it only works on tables with only 1 Primary Key. I have tried the following testing:

By the way, I used `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 2.1.4` for this testing

Explicitly assign value for these columns set to auto-increment:

1. `Tenant.TenantID`

   **a. -99** : remains -99 after saving

   **b. 0** : becomes 1 after saving

   **c. 99** : remains 99 after saving
2. For `Project.ProjectID` & `Credits.CreditsID`

   a. -99 & 99 values remains the same after saving changes to DbContext. But I do not want to explicitly assign these values because there are bunch of test data from my DbContext.

   b. Assigning explicit value 0 throws this error: `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: Credits.CreditsID'.`

I'd really be grateful for someone who can help me out with this one. It's been days that this bothers me.

Comment: Side note: I would not make TenantID part of the primary key for Project, and would not make ProjectID and TenantID part of the primary key for Credit. Just have a single PK column for each table and one foreign key to the parent (i.e. don't have a TenantID at all in Credit). It will make data management MUCH easier if you have to change a reference.

Comment: While I may agree with your plan because it is my usual way of db design, for this project, the db designer have it this way because he planned to have this partitioned.

Answer (score 2):

With SQLite you probably do not want to use AUTOINCREMENT, this does not actually set the column to increment rather it sets a constraint that the value, if not set explicitly must be a higher value than has been allocated.

Simply defining a column using INTEGER PRIMARY KEY sets the column to increment if not explicitly setting the value. Noting that there can only be one such column per table.

- Note that SQLite DOES NOT guarantee incrementing by 1 rather it guarantees a unique identifier which is an integer and may even be less (only after and id of  9223372036854775807 has been assigned).[SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html). In which case using AUTOINCREMENT will fail with an SQLIte Full exception, whilst without AUTOINCREMENT SQLite will try to find an unused id.

Looking at your diagram I believe the the Credits table would not need the TennantID as this is available via the Project referencing the Tennant.

Ignoring other than the columns that make up the relationships (also adding the optional foreign key restraints that would enforce referential integrity) then I believe you could use something along the lines of :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS credits;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS project;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tennant;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tennant (tennant_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, other_columns);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS project (project_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, tennant_reference REFERENCES tennant(tennant_id), Title);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS credits (credit_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, project_reference INTEGER REFERENCES project(project_id), other_columns TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS creidts (credit_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, project_reference INTEGER, other_columns);
INSERT INTO tennant VALUES(1,'Fred','other data'); -- Explicit ID 1
INSERT INTO tennant (Name,other_columns) VALUES('Mary','Mary''s other data'),('Anne','Anne''s other data'); -- Implicit ID 's (2 and 3 most likely)
INSERT INTO project VALUES (99,1,'Project001 for Fred'); --  Explicit Project ID 99 - tennant 1 = Fred
INSERT INTO project (tennant_reference,Title) VALUES(1,'Project002 for Fred'),(2,'Project003 for Mary'),(3,'Project004 for Anne'); -- 3 implicit project id's 100,101 and 102 (most likely)

-- Result 1
SELECT * FROM project JOIN tennant ON tennant_reference = tennant.tennant_id;

INSERT INTO credits VALUES(199,99,'Other credit columns'); -- Explicit credit ID of 199 for Project001 (tennant implied) 
INSERT INTO credits VALUES(0,99,'Other credit colums credit_id = 0'); -- Explicit credit ID of 0 for Project002
INSERT INTO credits (project_reference,other_columns) VALUES (100,'for Project002'),(100,'another for Project002'),(102,'for Project004');

SELECT * FROM credits JOIN project ON project_reference = project_id JOIN tennant ON tennant_reference = tennant_id;
```

- This drops all the existing tables to make testing simpler.
- The 3 tables are then created.
- Rows are inserted both explicitly and implicitly (the recommended way) into the Tennant table and then into the Project table (note that rows that reference a non-existent tennant cannot be inserted into the Project table due to the foreign key constraint)
- The Projects, along with the joined tennant details are then listed (see Results)
- Rows are then inserted into the Credits table using Explicit and Implicit credit id's (note that 199 is Explicitly defined and then 0).
- As you can see when id's are autogenerated they generally are 1 greater than the greatest value used to date.

### Results

#### First query (Project's with related Tennant)

[image]

#### Second Query Credits with related Project and the underlying related Tennant

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for the explanation. While this helps a lot, I have little control over the design - I would put it that way.  For this project, the db designer have it this way because he planned to have this partitioned.